# Namespaces and intellisense not working in droid project in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

New App() ==> is not resolved
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this,bundle) ==> is not resolved.

Everytime I create a new project, I face this issue. any suggestions please.

Comment: I face this issue from time to time on VS for Mac, in order to bring back the intellisense I 'Unload' and then 'Reload' the platform project.

Comment: When this happens, I do a lot of this random things and hope that it'll work. Unload, reload the project. Delete all the bin/obj folder, rebuild it. Restart VS. Or even uninstall the nugets and reinstall it all back. None of it make any sense, but sometimes it works... and I still have no idea why/how...

Answer (score 3):

See Michael Rumpler's final comment at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/62533/no-intellisense-in-cs-files-in-android-project

You should

**(1)** build your Android Project

**(2)** Go to File->Close Solution, but keep VS open

**(3)** Reopen the solution in the same VS instance.